# react-native can't found android-studio

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Hello I already start working with react-native, I faced a problem react-native can not find `android-studio` I can't figure it out, `Android studio` already installed on my OS using `snap`, if someone can help with this !!

```
$> react-native doctor
Common
 ✓ Node.js
 ✓ npm

Android
 ✓ JDK
 ✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME

Errors:   1
Warnings: 0

Usage
 › Press f to try to fix issues.
 › Press e to try to fix errors.
 › Press w to try to fix warnings.
 › Press Enter to exit.
```

Comment: were you able to fix this?